# JQuery Syntax Help Slider move DIVS based on autoheight

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using a simple jquery to rotate images (fade) and have an autoheight for each image (think I got that below).

Is it possible to change the height of #top-left div, based on the image height, and move the DIVs below it up.. is there some sort of fade function that would move the divs below up or down?

```
<div id="top-left">
<div class="slides">
    <img src="img/home-n1.jpg">
    <img src="img/home-n2.jpg">
    <img src="img/home-n3.jpg">
    <img src="img/home-n4.jpg">
</div>
</div>


$('.slides').cycle({
    fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    height: function() { 
        var c = jQuery('.slides img');
        jQuery('#top-left .slides').height(c.height()); 
    }
});
```

Some sort of mixing of these two ?

```
height: function() { 
    var c = jQuery('.slides img');
    jQuery('#top-left .slides').height(c.height()); 
    $("#top-left").animate({
        height: "70%",
        opacity: 0.4,
    }, 1500 );
}
```

Comment: Going to need more info to answer this question. Show the HTML, and relavent parts of the javascript at least.

Answer (score 0):

Use the before callback: [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/829pB/)

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement){
        var c = $(currSlideElement).height(),
            n = $(nextSlideElement).height(),
            diff = Math.abs(c - n),
            sign = c < n ? '+=' : '-=';

        $('.slideshow').delay(300).animate({ height: sign + diff });
    }
});
```